# Enable Fly-Out Quicklaunch menu without editing Master Page

Tags: sharepoint-online, quick-launch

I would like to enable Fly-Out menus on the Quicklaunch menu. I could do this easily while editing the Master Page (change "MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels").

But.. we are using SharePoint Online in Office 365 and Microsoft recommends not changing the Master Pages.

How can I make this happen? Is there a javascript solution for this for instance?

Comment: It's absolutely doable but as far as my  (and yours probably) research goes, there is no solution at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to use javascript injection to add javascript file to the page.

Example (1) - [Customize your SharePoint site UI by using JavaScript](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/pnp_articles/customize-your-sharepoint-site-ui-by-using-javascript?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Example (2) - [JavaScript injection in SharePoint Online - Office 365 Developer Patterns and Practices](https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/Office-365-Dev/JavaScript-injection-in-SharePoint-Online-Office-365-Developer-Patterns-and-Practices)

Once you are able to inject js, then in that js , write the below mentioned code. I got the code from this blog by Marc Anderson's [blog](http://sympmarc.com/2015/05/27/simple-expandcollapse-for-the-quick-launch-in-sharepoint-2013-or-sharepoint-online/). Hope this  slightly modified code helps you. Just ensure that jquery is loaded before this code is executed:

```
    // Find all the top level links in the Quick Launch that have children
var topLevelLinks = $("div[id$='QuickLaunchMenu'] > ul > li:has('ul') > a");

// Prepend the little "twiddle" icon to each top level link
topLevelLinks.prepend("<span class='ms-commentexpand-iconouter ql-icon'><img alt='expand' src='/Comm/Comms2/_themes/1/spcommon-B35BB0A9.themedpng?ctag=2' class='ms-commentexpand-icon'></span>");

// We're starting with all of the sections collapsed. If you want them expanded, comment this out.
topLevelLinks.closest("li").find("> ul").hide();

// Set up for the click even of on the top level links
//topLevelLinks.click - existing code
topLevelLinks.hover(function(e) {

  // We're going to stop the default behavior
  e.preventDefault();

  // Find the elements we need to work with
  var childUl = $(this).closest("li").find("> ul");
  var isVisible = childUl.is(":visible")

  // If the section is visible, hide it, and vice versa
  if(isVisible) {  

    // Replace the icon with its antitheses
    $(this).find(".ql-icon").replaceWith("<span class='ms-commentexpand-iconouter ql-icon'><img alt='Expand' src='/Comm/Comms2/_themes/1/spcommon-B35BB0A9.themedpng?ctag=2' class='ms-commentexpand-icon'></span>");
    // Hide the child links by sliding up. Note: You could change the effect here.
    childUl.slideUp();

  } else {

    // Replace the icon with its antitheses
    $(this).find(".ql-icon").replaceWith("<span class='ms-commentcollapse-iconouter ql-icon'><img alt='Collapse' src='/Comm/Comms2/_themes/1/spcommon-B35BB0A9.themedpng?ctag=2' class='ms-commentcollapse-icon'></span>");
    // Show the child links by sliding down. Note: You could change the effect here.
    childUl.slideDown();

  }

});
```